# BeautifulSoup generating inconsistent results

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to pull data out of Reddit sidebars on a selection of subreddits, but my results are changing pretty much every time I run my script.

Specifically, the results in `sidebar_urls` changes from iteration to iteration; sometimes it will result in `[XYZ.com/abc, XYZ.com/def]`, other times it will return just `[XYZ.com/def]`, and finally, it will sometimes return `[]`.

Any ideas why this might be happening using the code below?

```
sidebar_urls = []

for i in range(0, len(reddit_urls)):
    req = urllib.request.Request(reddit_urls[i], headers=headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp, 'html.parser')

    links = soup.find_all(href=True)

    for link in links:
        if "XYZ.com" in str(link['href']):
            sidebar_urls.append(link['href'])
```

Comment: Can you provide us with `reddit_urls`?

Comment: The two I've been testing before I go to a broader list are `/r/leagueoflegends`
and `/r/pokemon` @Pierre

Comment: When you say "sidebar", which part of the page are you referring to? Can you provide an example of a few elements that you would expect to be properly scraped?

Comment: I want to be able to scrape the links in the sidebar on the right side of the page (the black sidebar in `/r/leagueoflegends`, for example). I noticed this after realizing that some iterations of my script would generate a link to the Discord server that the `/r/leagueoflegends` page links to, and other times, the Discord link wouldn't show up. @Pierre

Comment: This would be a lot easier to debug if you were working with the same html text every time, so you would know exactly what to expect.  Save one request to a file and then work with that file until the bugs are gone, then go back to parsing the live page.

Comment: I never resolved the actual issue here, but ended up getting around it by just calling the json version of the url with `requests.get`, which always provided the sidebar content I was looking for. Not a generic solution, but one that solved the problem for reddit scrapes, at least.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you sometimes get a page that does not have a side bar. It could be because Reddit is recognizing you as a robot and returning a default page instead of the one you expect. Consider identifying yourself when requesting the pages, using the `User-Agent` field:

```
reddit_urls = [
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/",
    "https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/"
]

# Update this to identify yourself
user_agent = "me@example.com"

sidebar_urls = []
for reddit_url in reddit_urls:
    response = requests.get(reddit_url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    # Find the sidebar tag
    side_tag = soup.find("div", {"class": "side"})
    if side_tag is None:
        print("Could not find a sidebar in page: {}".format(reddit_url))
        continue

    # Find all links in the sidebar tag
    link_tags = side_tag.find_all("a")
    for link in link_tags:
        link_text = str(link["href"])
        sidebar_urls.append(link_text)

print(sidebar_urls)
```